# Bad practice? Leaving out for loop condition

Tags: java, for-loop, syntax, conditional-statements, chess

I am working on a chess game and right now I am making a method to check from the king, in a direction and returns true if a threat is found, false if no threat is found.
This method takes in two ints to increase x and y by. And this method will from the starting location, in the direction given ( (1,0) for up, (1,1) for up&right, (0,1) for down).

My problem is, this method checks the path with a for loop, which will eventually hit the border of the chess game, and find a barrier, or it will find a piece. Either way, that is how the for loop should end. But then what condition would go in the for loop? 
I feel like it might be bad practice to just leave it out, but then the only logical condition would be to make sure x and y are both in the range of 1-8. But that would leave the code looking like :
`for(int i = begx + xdiff, j = begy + ydiff; (i < 8 && i > 1) && (j < 8 && j > 1); i += xdiff, j += ydiff) { .. }`

This would be the only other option I see, and this in itself seems like bad practice to me also. Because, it looks over complicated and crammed together. And this condition should never be broken, so why would I have it in there if it would never be the reason the loop broke? I don't want other programmers to read my code and think this might be something they have to look out for, when really, I just didn't need a condition there and put it in for double checking.

This is the whole method, for reference:

```
public boolean incheckPath(Location l1, int xdiff, int ydiff) {
    int begx = l1.getX();
    int begy = l1.getY();

    String team = board[begx][begy].getTeam();

    for(int i = begx + xdiff, j = begy + ydiff; ; i += xdiff, j += ydiff) {
        if(board[i][j].getType() != ' ') {

            if(board[i][j].getType() == '#') {
                return false;
            }
            if(board[i][j].getTeam().equals(team)) {
                return false;
            }
            if(board[i][j].getType() == 'Q' || board[i][j].getType() == 'R') {
                return true;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT**
It has been improved to implement a while loop, but now how could this be improved any? Someone suggested using break and continue so I implemented that where I saw it could be. But, someone said I shouldn't return in a loop. Without making a variable to hold the return value, how would this be possible?

```
public boolean incheckPath(Location l1, int xdiff, int ydiff) {
    int x = l1.getX();
    int y = l1.getY();

    String team = board[x][y].getTeam();

    while(true) {
        x += xdiff;
        y += ydiff;

        if(board[x][y].getType() == '#' || board[x][y].getTeam().equals(team)) {
            break;
        }

        if(board[x][y].getType() == 'Q' || board[x][y].getType() == 'R') {
            return true;
        }

    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: So, I'm not clear. You just want a way to iterate through the possible moves of the piece?

Comment: @GGrec - The code does compile, its a completely working chess game, I'm just changing a few methods around. Do you have anything constructive to say?

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with leaving out the loop condition or setting it to `true` or whatever when the terminating condition is a `break` or `return`.  (We'll leave the argument about returning from inside a loop for another day.)

Comment: @JoshF - No, I am going outward from the king to see if there are any possible threats.

Comment: @MatthewC Yeah. Avoid hardcoding strings. Learn to use `continue` for code readability, and `break` for performance. Combine those IF statements. Your code is fine.

Comment: I'd be inclined to not use a `for` at all, but use a `while(true)` and set up the loop control variables externally.  As it is, they're hard to follow inside the `for`, and would be clearer broken out as separate lines.

Comment: @GGrec How would I prevent hardcoding the string? And how would you implement break and continue here?

Comment: Larger change than you ask for, but I find it strange that the method for checking if the king is in danger needs to search each square around him. (Does this also account for the knight's L movement?) I think I would keep a list of possible moves on each piece and then compare each enemy piece's possible moves to the kings position.

Comment: It does indeed test for every possible spot. It was just much easier to group these together because they are whole lines rather than just spots. My isInCheck method first calls this method to test every line then if there are no threats in any of them, it will look for other possible threats. Like, the 8 spots a Knight could be around the king, and the two spots that pawns could attack a king from.

Comment: This code is fine as it is. For performance though, I would check that the compiler is generating code that caches the result from the getType calls or is inlining those calls and using common subexpression-type optimization I doubt that you want to be making three calls to that getType method in the underlying code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is more readable as a `while` loop:

```
    int i = begx + xdiff;
    int j = begy + ydiff;
    while (true) {
        if(board[i][j].getType() != ' ') {
            if(board[i][j].getType() == '#') {
                return false;
            }
            if(board[i][j].getTeam().equals(team)) {
                return false;
            }
            if(board[i][j].getType() == 'Q' || board[i][j].getType() == 'R') {
                return true;
            }
        }
        i += xdiff; 
        j += ydiff;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are determining on your own, based on other code you wrote, when the `for` loop should end, then you should declare a boolean

`boolean keepLooping = true`

and set it to false when you want the loop to stop.  Note that you have to do this inside the for loop.

Now make that the condition of the loop the variable you just created.  In other words it would say `...; keepLooping ; ...`

Also, I'm not sure about your implementation of getType, which might return a character.  If it returns a string, you probably don't mean to use `==` to compare strings.  You want to use `oneString.equals(anotherString)` to check if they are **equivalent**.  Using == actually checks to see if they are literally the same variable in memory.  Probably this is not what you want.

So in that case your code would look like

```
if(board[i][j].getType().equals("Q")   ......
```

But if getType returns a character, this paragraph does not apply.

Comment: I take `getType() == 'Q'` to mean it is returning a char Q rather than a string. Which should be fine. I otherwise agree with using a while loop and a boolean.

Comment: getType returns a char, that part is fine.

Comment: I overlooked that single quote  String str = 'contentsOfMyString' is not valid in java, edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of problem, it's best to use a while loop

use a `boolean loop = True;`

while(loop){...};

You could then use your return statements to quit the loop

Answer (score 0):

I would compare the possible moves from enemy pieces to the King's position, rather than every pieces' possible moves from the King's position.
Little picture to demonstrate because I am bad with figuring out how to word that.

```
       C        C
       C     C   
   "P" C  C       //P is Pawn
 C  C "K" C  C  C //K is King
    C  C  C       //C is where you (potentially) had to check
 C     C     C   



   "P"            //P is Pawn
 C    "K"         //K is King
                  //C is where you (potentially) had to check
```

Now, I put that situation in my favor, since there is only one piece and it scales with number of pieces. But the reason I would do this is:

once you have the list of possible moves you can use it for other things as well, such as making sure a move is valid, and scoring which move is best. (You may even have a list or array already for this purpose)

I realize that would mean recoding a large chunk of what you have. (Which sounds like it is already working), but thought I would throw it out there.

Comment: That would take up twice as much code and be ineffecient. Your diagram makes it look like it would be faster and have less places to check, but that's because the enemy had only one piece. With more, and with no way to tell which ones are in range of the king, you would have to test every single move of every single piece of the enemy team. Instead of just every move of our king.

Comment: @MatthewC When you consider only this situation than you are correct (as I also pointed out in my post), but I stick with what I said. A king is put in check AFTER a piece is moved, thus you only need to check the moved piece's moves, and the moves of pieces that were blocked by the moved piece. If you are keeping a list of available moves for each piece, (such as for AI purposes), you are updating similar logic anyway.